# Query that only uses index takes long time to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I have a table with ~69,000 rows. I have this very simple query:

```
-- SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Customers
-- SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 31 ms, elapsed time = 901 ms.
```

I also have this non clustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1 ON Customers (LastName ASC, FirstName ASC, ID ASC) WITH (
PAD_INDEX = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
ONLINE = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON PRIMARY
```

The execution plan indicates that this index is being used. Yet the query takes ~1 second to return 69k rows which seems odd to me. I am wondering if 1 second is an acceptable amount of time or is it possible to improve this query.

**Edit 1:**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)
>    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

It runs on a dedicated Dell PowerEdge server with 16GB RAM and two SCSI hard drives.

**Edit 2:**

I get almost similar timings (~1 second) even if I run the query on the server itself using named pipes/shared memory/TCP connections.

Comment: How much time does the following query take? `DECLARE @ID INT, @FirstName VARCHAR(50), @LastName VARCHAR(50);SELECT @ID=ID, @FirstName=FirstName, @LastName=LastName FROM Customers` this will take the overhead of transferring and processing 69K rows out of the equation.

Comment: I don't think you can find an index better than this. The query has to either scan the whole table or this index. Assuming that the table has more columns, the index should be (slightly or heavily) the best. But you haven't provided any info on the workload of the table (or the database or the SQL-Server instance) or the machine characteristics (memory, disks). The problem probably lies elsewhere and not in the index.

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes, it took ~0.065 seconds. What can be done to improve it?

Comment: @ypercube: you are right. I have added hardware details but I am not sure where to look for improvement.

Comment: ~1 second to return to what? The time you're seeing is properly the time the "thing" (for example management studio) uses to receives and display the data

Comment: So the difference between the two timings is largely down to the length of time it takes to transfer the 69,000 rows to the client and for the client to process them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may just be taking a while to return to the client.  How long does it take if you run as SELECT INTO, eg

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName 
INTO #tmp 
FROM Customers
```

Comment: Yes, that is what it was... Transferring few MBs worth of data from server to client.